# What is the difference in database of magento C.E 1.9 when compare with magento C.E 1.8?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8

Is there any difference in database of magento C.E 1.9 when compare with magento C.E 1.8?

Whether in structure or fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copied all table names to text document from 1.8.x and from 1.9.1.0, then opened win merge:

**exists only in 1.8:**

```
review_detail
xmlconnect_application
xmlconnect_config_data
xmlconnect_history
xmlconnect_images
xmlconnect_notification_template
xmlconnect_queue
```

**exists only in 1.9:**

```
core_email_queue
core_email_queue_recipients
review_entity_summary
```

Comment: Table names but what about the content of table? Is there any column changes occurred? I am so sorry to ask that, the reason is that i can not find 1.8 version anywhere to download myself.

Comment: http://magento.com/blog/magento-news/magento-community-edition-1800-now-available

Comment: Can not download 1.8 version anymore.

Comment: I can share it. Give your gmail

Comment: How can i give you my gmail? Could you maybe share a temporary link instead zhartaunik where i can download version 1.8?

Comment: Sorry for not-responding during holidays http://www.filedropper.com/magento-1810tar